# Compatibility error on WCF rest service

Tags: asp.net, wcf-rest

when I added

`[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]`

in wcf rest service and

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
```

in webconfig
 im getting error as

The service cannot be activated because it does not support ASP.NET compatibility. ASP.NET compatibility is enabled for this application. Turn off ASP.NET compatibility mode in the web.config or add the AspNetCompatibilityRequirements attribute to the service type with RequirementsMode setting as 'Allowed' or 'Required'.

Actually its working fine when I run service in localhost but its throwing the error when I host the service..
Actually I need this bcos im planning to implement caching in wcf rest service..
Please help ....

Comment: I came to know that as im integrating servicebus eventhough i added the above mentioned attribute it wont work  as per this link 

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/11/17/wcf-rest-http-application-connecting-azure-service-bus-using-webhttprelaybinding-causes-aspnetcompatibilityenabled-error.aspx

and I need to implement caching and as per below link the above menioned attribute is required for caching

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230443.aspx

please let me know how can implement caching

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by updating you web.config file as follows:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
        </authentication>   
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I added as below  <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"></transport>
            <authentication>
              <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
</security> but it says the element security has invalid childelement authentication..
And before adding wat u have suggested the basicauthentication is disabled for the hosted WCF restservice  in IIS